# Need help solving Project Euler problem #35 python?

Tags: python

I,ve ran into this problem on Project Euler, the question is

> The number, 197, is called a circular prime because all rotations of
>   the digits: 197, 971, and 719, are themselves prime.
>
> There are thirteen such primes below 100: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 31,
>   37, 71, 73, 79, and 97.
>
> How many circular primes are there below one million?

After many variations my code looks like this:

```
def circularPrimes(n):
  primeList, sieve, circularPrime = [], [True] * n, True
  for p in range(2,n):
    if sieve[p]:
      pi = str(p)
      for i in range(0,len(pi)):
        rotatedNumber = pi[i:len(pi)] + pi[0:i]
        rotatedNumber1 = int(rotatedNumber)
        if not sieve[rotatedNumber1]:
          circularPrime = False
      if circularPrime:
        primeList.append(p)
      for i in range(p*p,n,p):
        sieve[i] = False
  return len(primeList)
print(circularPrimes(1000000))
```

Why isn't it working and why is it returning 7 no matter what I put?
All criticism appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never reset `circularPrime` to `True`, so once it's `False`, it stays `False` for all future numbers you test. Also, you are checking the rotations of the current number before completing the sieve, but then you do not know yet if those rotation (which could be greater than the original number) really are prime. If you separate the sieve-creation and the rotations-checking it should work:

```
def circularPrimes(n):
    primeList, sieve = [], [True] * n
    for p in range(2,n):
        if sieve[p]:
            for i in range(p*p,n,p):
                sieve[i] = False
    for p in range(2,n):
        if sieve[p]:
            circularPrime = True
            pi = str(p)
            for i in range(0,len(pi)):
                rotatedNumber = pi[i:len(pi)] + pi[0:i]
                rotatedNumber1 = int(rotatedNumber)
                if not sieve[rotatedNumber1]:
                    circularPrime = False
            if circularPrime:
                primeList.append(p)
    return len(primeList)
```

(Interestingly, it gives the same (correct) result even if you just reset `circularPrime` in each iteration, but this might be a coincidence, or have deeper mathematical reasons I don't understand.)